# What does the weird "e" or "t" in Chrome's console indicate

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, javascript-objects, typescript3.0

I'm trying to debug a weird problem I face with TypeScript 3.1, Babel 7 and Webpack 4, where it only works when I build an object manually. Here's an example (pseudo code):

**B** *(see img below)*:

```
const objectOfObjects = {...}
const someKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

someKeys.filter(key => {
  const i = new Foo(objectOfObjects[key]['somePropName'], /* subsequent props */);
  console.log(i); // when I inspect the object here values are set correctly
  return predicate(i);
});
```

But instead of having to type that in manually `objectOfObjects[key]['somePropName']` for each property, I just pass in an object of a given TypeScript interface, and pass that to the constructor and let it Object.assign it.

**A** *(see img below)*:

```
const objectOfObjects = {...}
const someKeys = ['key1', 'key2', 'key3']

someKeys.filter(key => {
  const i = new Foo(objectOfObjects[key]);
  console.log(i) // this does also return and object, but with all props undefined
  return predicate(i);
});
```

Foo extends the following base class

```
class FooBase {
  constructor(o: IFoo) {
    if (o) {
      Object.assign(this, o);
    }
  }
}
```

When I make a very simple example it seems to be working, but no matter what, when I pass `objectOfObjects[key]` to the constructor of Foo in my real application I get this:

[image]

As I've gone over it and tried to find changes in `objectOfObjects[key]`, the only difference I can think of is what i highlighted in the image above - the little "e" and "t" just to the left of the object in chrome console. I could not find any documentation from a google search, so hopefully one of you knows what it means, and hopefully it could also indicate what I do wrong here.

Comment: It's a great question. I don't find either answer below to be satisfactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Ted Hopp already said, it is hard to tell what is going on there from the small pieces you provided.

I think in A you have only the constructor of `f t(e)` because it is the constructor from `IFoo` copied due to a flat reference copy.

`Object.assign()` only makes a flat copy and ignores all `undefined` and `null` values. Maybe make a quick check: Since you are calling `const i = new Foo(objectOfObjects[key]);` the object `objectOfObjects[key]` needs to be an `IFoo` and needs to have all the values, you want to flat copy.

Since unfolding an object is done lazy in the debuggers, you could try to hit a breakpoint there and check again what the object really contains.

Honestly, these are only guesses and this answer will maybe removed later by me.

Comment: Thanks, In my concreate case, the problem was caused by loading plugins and presets in the wrong order in my webpack config. Cause all sorts of weird errors, because code was transformed before babels preset-typescript did its magic.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell without knowing anything about what a `Foo` is, but those appear to be property names within the object you logged. The TypeScript compiler generates properties like this when it compiles your code into JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Ted, but if the typescript compiler generated those (e and t) just to the left of the object in the console, do you have any idea why properties are always undefined when there's an "t" and always fine when there's a "e". What is it trying to tell me? :-)

Comment: @Dac0d3r - I don't think it's trying to tell you anything. You can probably ignore them. Those are probably internal bookkeeping data based on your class definitions. Perhaps if you showed us the class definitions and didn't black out so much of the console output I could make a guess, but as it is I have no idea why the property values are set that way. Also, the "e" property is not undefined (otherwise, there would just be a single line "undefined" next to the name and no expansion arrow to the left of it).

Comment: Sorry, corporate data, but it's basically just showing the exact same keys/values :/ Just an observation: if you look closely in the bottom line of the picture, you can see: f  t(e) for construct A and f  e(t,n,r,o, ... all the individual props) for construct B. Still not sure what it means, just an observation, since they may be related. I'll try to see if I can share some more code